# Why can't I read math expression from a file when dollar sign is redefined?

Tags: math-mode

This code works just fine (and prints `[x=y]` in math mode):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[1]{$[#1]$}
\begingroup
\catcode`\$=\active
\protected\gdef$#1${\foo{#1}}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\$=\active}
\begin{document}
$x = y$
\end{document}
```

However, if I read the same text (`$[x=y]$`) from a file, it fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\input{a.tex}}
\begingroup
\catcode`\$=\active
\protected\gdef$#1${\foo{#1}}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\$=\active}
\begin{document}
$x = y$
\end{document}
```

Is it fixable?

If you wonder what I'm trying to achieve: I want dollar sign to mean something bigger in my documents than it usually means. I want to wrap every usage of `$...$` by my own command `\foo` and add additional formatting *and* parsing to it through an external script that I use via `\write18`.

Comment: I don't get it, what content do you have in a.tex and what do you want the output to be?

Comment: I have `[$x=y$]` in `a.txt`. I'm expecting the same output at the second snippet as I get with the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\catcode`\$=3 \input{h.tex}\catcode`\$\active}
\begingroup
\catcode`\$=\active
\protected\gdef$#1${\foo{#1}}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\$=\active}
\begin{document}
$x = y$
\end{document}
```

Assuming h.tex contains `$x=y$` this will print out `x=y` in math mode.

Comment: (I don't know if OP wants to learn how catcode works or not, but if OP or any future reader is interested the documentation can be found in TeXbook -- basically `\input` will only tokenize the content in the file when it's executed, and it's desirable for `$` to have math catcode instead of active when the file is tokenized so we don't get infinite loop)

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices: either you use `\(...\)` in the file you write out (to be read in later) or change the category code of `$` before inputting the file.

While I recommend the first method, here's how you can do the latter (and also how to remove the spurious space you get when doing `\input` while typesetting a paragraph.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-a.tex}
$[x=y]$
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\foo[1]{\inputnodollar{\jobname-a.tex}}
\newcommand{\inputnodollar}[1]{\begingroup\catcode`$=3 \input{#1}\unskip\endgroup}

\begingroup
\catcode`$=\active
\protected\gdef$#1${\foo{#1}}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`$=\active}

\begin{document}

X$x = y$X

X$x = y$ X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the `\unskip` you'd get one space after the formula in the first line and two in the second line.

Instead of `\unskip`, if your input files are one liner, you can set `\endlinechar` to –1

```
\newcommand{\inputnodollar}[1]{\begingroup\catcode`$=3 \endlinechar=-1 \input{#1}\endgroup}
```